# What am I? Short riddle 3

Tags: riddle

> There are always two of my kind in any group of people
>   I am the beginning of an emperor
>   But nowhere in his second-in-command
>   You can argue I'm dirty
>   Well, I *am* dirty, and smelly too
>   What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> The letter 'p'?

There are always two of my kind in any group of people

> There are two 'p's in 'people'.

I am the beginning of an emperor

> em**p**eror

But nowhere in his second-in-command

> There is no 'p' in 'second-in-command'

You can argue I'm dirty

> There's a slightly taboo word that starts with  'p'

Well, I am dirty, and smelly too

> Like, poo.

Comment: @boboquack - it's in the first half. But yeah, I couldn't really make that line fit.

Comment: When I said pee, I meant for the last line

Comment: I dont get the beginning part. It should have been *in the beginning* I guess

Comment: @Techidiot - quite possible.

Comment: @Techidiot The second and third are reference to the fourth, fifth, and sixth.